# Global variables are empty even though they've been set within a sub vba

Tags: vba, excel, scope, global-variables, is-empty

Tried to create a timer in VBA. My intetion is to be able to call `TimerStart`, `TimerLaps` and `TimerStop` within other funcitions to estimate how long it takes a code block to finish. But I'm having problems with my global variable being empty.

```
Private starttime As Double   

Sub TimerStart()
    starttime = Timer
End Sub

Function TimerLaps() As Double
    TimerLaps = Timer - starttime
End Function

Function TimerStop() As Double
    i = starttime
    starttime = 0
    TimerStop = Round(Timer - i, 2)
End Function

Sub test()
    Call TimerStart

    MsgBox TimerStop()
End Sub
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: I've also tried seting starttime as global and public, but it still does'nt work. I've set it as private because it makes sence that the scope is within the module in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Global starttime As Double
```

At the top of your module
(instead of `Private starttime As Double`)

**EDIT**

```
Global starttime As Double

Sub test()
    Call TimerStart
    Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
    MsgBox TimerStop()
End Sub

Sub TimerStart()
    starttime = Timer
End Sub

Function TimerStop() As Double
    Dim i As Double
    i = starttime
    starttime = 0
    TimerStop = Round(Timer - i, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it does'nt work. When TimerStop() is called starttime is empty.

Comment: I'm assuming you called TimerStart first? Running the sub 'test' works for me... (except it obv runs so quickly that the time is 0)

Comment: Ok. Maybe i did'nt ask the question right. I get the time different, but i want the resault to be the seconds elapsed from when i call timerstart untill timerstop. If I put ´Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)´ between ´Call TimerStart´ and ´MsgBox TimerStop()´ in ´Sub Test()´, I want the output to be around 2 seconds.

Comment: Then it's not my logic however, but it still doesnt work. It is so frustrating... Can it be because of some settings in my VBA version or something?

Comment: struggling to work out why that could be. have you stepped through the code line by line using F8? and you can watch in the locals window to try and see where it's not doing what you think it is.

Comment: Are you placing the public variable in a standard code module? If it is placed in a userform module for example then the variable remains in memory only while the userform is active.

Comment: Also, if you have "End" on its own in a line anywhere in the code then that will cause all public variables to lose their values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in two way:

```
Global starttime As Double
```

And

```
Public starttime As Double
```

Use one of them instead of `Private`. The main different is:

> **Global** can only be used in standard modules, whereas **Public** can be used in all contexts (modules, classes, controls, forms etc.) 
> **Global** comes from older versions of VB and was likely kept for backwards compatibility, but has been wholly superseded by **Public**.

Comment: I've tried it, but it does'nt work. When TimerStop() is called starttime is empty.

Comment: I tested with `Public`, I got right message. Yes, starttime will be 0 because `starttime = 0`. But you will get the time different.

Comment: Ok. Maybe i did'nt ask the question right. I get the time different, but i want the resault to be the seconds elapsed from when i call timerstart untill timerstop. If I put ´Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)´  between ´Call TimerStart´ and ´MsgBox TimerStop()´ in ´Sub Test()´, I want the output to be around 2 seconds.